# How to pass multiple parameters with JSON on Servlet to Ajax

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

I have JavaScript code that should get two parameters from servlet:
player name and player type (Human \ Computer)

The JavaScript use Ajax to send the request to the servlet named: UpdateStatusPaneServlet.java

On the servlet I created `ArrayList<String>` of 2 parameters and sent it to the Ajax.

You can see in the picture that the array appears ok.

I am not sure how to get the parameters using the `indexOf()` function or maybe I need to use other function.
I also tried with `get()` but it didn't work.
Also with playerNameAndType[0] it just print `'['`

[image]

**JavaScript**:

```
function printStatusPane() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "UpdateStatusPaneServlet",
        timeout: 2000,
        error: function() {
            console.log("Failed to send ajax");
        },
        success: function(playerNameAndType) {
            console.log("GOT ajax: " + playerNameAndType);
            $("#currentPlayer").append(playerNameAndType.indexOf(0));
            $("#playerType").append(playerNameAndType.indexOf(1));
        }
    });
}
```

**Servlet (Java)**:

```
  protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
         response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String currentPlayerNameJSON = "";
            String playerTypeJSON = "";
            Engine engine = (Engine)getServletContext().getAttribute("engine");
            ArrayList<String> JSONRequest = new ArrayList<String>(2);

            currentPlayerNameJSON = gson.toJson(engine.GetCurrentPlayer().GetPlayerName());
            playerTypeJSON = gson.toJson(engine.GetCurrentPlayer().GetPlayerType().toString());

            JSONRequest.add(currentPlayerNameJSON);
            JSONRequest.add(playerTypeJSON);
            out.print(JSONRequest);

        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what does your console prints for playerNameAndType ??

Comment: can you also try the following?  var test = [];
test = playerNameAndType; and try to get test[0] to print

Comment: try to convert it to json using JSON.parse(playerNameAndType) and then access it using index. `var obj = JSON.parse(playerNameAndType); obj[0]`

Comment: @KumarKailash, when type playerNameAndType I receive on the console: "["Bob", "Human"]"

Comment: you said you are receiving  "["Bob", "Human"]" . Just do $("#currentPlayer").append(playerNameAndType[0]);
$("#playerType").append(playerNameAndType[1]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following  D.T. comment I fixed it:

```
  var arrayJson = JSON.parse(playerNameAndType); 
  $("#currentPlayer").append(arrayJson[0]);
  $("#playerType").append(arrayJson[1]);
```

And it prints it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` returns the position of the array value.Use key index to take the array value and append in to the id

```
playerNameAndType = ["Bob", "Human"];
$("#currentPlayer").append(playerNameAndType[0]);
$("#playerType").append(playerNameAndType[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, console output is `["Bob", "Human"]` You can access that directly by index :

```
$("#currentPlayer").append(playerNameAndType[0]);
$("#playerType").append(playerNameAndType[1]);
```

What `indexof()` return is index of element you passed in argument.

```
playerNameAndType.indexOf("Bob")
```

will give you `0`, the index of "Bob".

Example :

```js
var person = ["Bob", "Human"];
document.write("Hey, " + person[0] + "!! You are first in array.");
```

Comment: No, as I wrote on my question I tried it playerNameAndType[0] prints '['

Comment: But I am not receiving "var person = ["Bob", "John"];"
I received from the servlet some ArrayList<String> object that contains two objects and playerNameAndType[0] prints '['

Comment: In comment on question you said console output is `["Bob", "Human"]`. Unfortunately SO code runner does not support java code !! :( I can't provide runable java code here...!! So I take one variable which stores what exactly your console output is.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting an array of objects . Just simply retrieve the object from it's index .

```
$("#currentPlayer").append(playerNameAndType[0]);
$("#playerType").append(playerNameAndType[1]);
```

Comment: No, as I wrote on my question I tried it playerNameAndType[0] prints '['

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the below code

```
ArrayList<String> JSONRequest = new ArrayList<String>(2);
currentPlayerNameJSON = gson.toJson(engine.GetCurrentPlayer().GetPlayerName());
playerTypeJSON = gson.toJson(engine.GetCurrentPlayer().GetPlayerType().toString());
JSONRequest.add(currentPlayerNameJSON);
JSONRequest.add(playerTypeJSON);
out.print(JSONRequest);
```

Please try

```
currentPlayerNameJSON = gson.toJson(engine.GetCurrentPlayer().GetPlayerName());
playerTypeJSON = gson.toJson(engine.GetCurrentPlayer().GetPlayerType().toString());
HashMap<String, String> responseMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
resposeMap.put("name",currentPlayerNameJSON );
resposeMap.put("type",playerTypeJSON );
out.print(responseMap.toString());
```

and in the javaScript you can

```
function printStatusPane() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "UpdateStatusPaneServlet",
        timeout: 2000,
        error: function() {
            console.log("Failed to send ajax");
        },
        success: function(playerNameAndType) {
           var json = $.parseJSON(playerNameAndType);    
            $("#currentPlayer").append(json['name']);
            $("#playerType").append(json['type']);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an ArrayList-"JSONRequest" having Json objects from your servlet. Try converting your arraylist to Json by `JSON.stringify(JSONRequest)`. You can then handle this Json in client side.